# WSO2 5.3.0 - accountDisabled claim storage

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have `WSO2 IS 5.3.0` running in two environments which are completely independent of each other. In one environment, the `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled` is backed by the `UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE` table, and in the other it is backed by the `IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA`.

When I say backed, I mean that calls to `UserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues` returns the underlying data from the different tables (both environments are backed by independent MYSQL DBs)

I'm looking for direction on what configuration differences I should be looking for in order to make the behavior the same. So far I have verified that `claim-config.xml` is identical in both environments (see below).

```
<Claim>
    <ClaimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled</ClaimURI>
    <DisplayName>Account Disabled</DisplayName>
    <!-- Proper attribute Id in your user store must be configured for this -->
    <AttributeID>ref</AttributeID>
    <Description>Account Disabled</Description>
    <SupportedByDefault />
</Claim>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the EventListener configuration with name `org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityStoreEventListener` in the `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` file.

`Data.Store` property should have `org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore` value when it is using claim values (for claim URIs that start with `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/*`) from IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA.

```
<EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityStoreEventListener"
                       orderId="97" enable="true">
    <Property name="Data.Store">org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore</Property>
</EventListener>
```

Comment: In the misbehaving environment, this EventListener wasn't enabled (though the property was correct). Thanks for you help